# How to get regex split from other var

Tags: php, mysql

```
$dbLink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 't');
mysql_select_db('pc_spec', $dbLink);
$html = file_get_contents('http://localhost/pc_spec/scrape.php?q=amd+955'); 
echo $html; 
$html = strip_tags($html);
$price = ereg("\$.{6}", $html);
$html = mysql_real_escape_string($html);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($price);
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO parts(part, price) values('$html','$price')") or  var_dump(mysql_error());
```

How can I get $price to match $.{6} and insert this value (eg. $111.11) into a database and remove it from $html? Do I need to use explode?

Thanks

Comment: ereg is depreciated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Dragon: understand that, what else would I use though?

Comment: you should use the preg_* functions.

Comment: Do you need to remove the price from `$html`? If so, a `str_replace($price, '', $html);` should do just fine.

Comment: I need to remove the price from $html and add the price to $price, which inserts it into another field in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use the perl compatible functions (pcre_*).

To get your price, this should do it:

```
preg_match('/\$.{6}/', $html, $price); // Get your price
$html = str_replace($price, '', $html); // Remove $price from $html
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO parts(part, price) values('$html','$price')") or  var_dump(mysql_error()); // Insert into db
```

This should do what you want. If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: Does not work http://codepad.org/SRJYFLKa. In MySQL under price it inserts 'Array'. It's VARCHAR(15).

Comment: Sorted, used $price[0] as its an array.

Answer (score 0):

in short, explode would work should you need to remove it from $html.

Comment: right, and how exactly do I go about it? I dont understand how Explode works. It takes stuff from a string and just expands it so you can remove certain things?

Comment: it takes a string and given a delimiter, turns it into an array. depending on what you need to take from $html, you can get it by array index...

Comment: but your SQL connection syntax it OK?